# Jupyter: Run specific cell everytime another cell is executed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am often using jupyter in the way, that I first define some functions:

```
# Cell 1
def calc_area(radius):
    return radius**2 * np.pi
```

Later is use this function for some application:

```
# Cell n
area_of_wheel = calc_area(radius_of_wheel)
```

Now this works totally fine, but it is very common for me, change something in the definition of the function, but I forget to execute that cell. In the best case I get an error, in the worst case, I get incorrect results, and I don't understand why. Is there something like a magic command, that executes a cell, everytime I run a different cell?
This is not a big deal, but would improve my workflow using jupyter. If relevant, I use Jupyter in VS Code.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Enter to run all cells of your notebook

Comment: I'm also adding you can press Shift + Enter to run a cell, and select all the cells below that one